# Run a method only if a tag or keyword is given using Python

Tags: python, annotations

I'm writing Selenium tests in Python and want to be able to tag certain sections of the script so that I can skip those sections if I specify it from the cmd line.  What I'm hoping for is something like this:

```
@run
def somemethod():
    print "this method should not run if the @run tag is False"
```

what I'd like to do from there is something like:

```
python script_name.py @run=False
```

or whatever format this should be in.  This should make it skip that method.

This is something that can obviously be done with an if statement, like so:

```
if not run:
    somemethod()
```

or put the if statement inside of the method.  However, I want to be able to write a tag from the command line, rather than having a ton of if-statements everywhere.  Does something like this exist, or is it functionality that I'd have to try to create?

What I'm using:

```
Python 2.7.9
Selenium 2.44   
Windows 7 and Linux
```

Comment: Don't be lazy. You would've already been done with the if statements. By the time you get an answer

Comment: there are a lot of scripts and lazy = ugly.  Trying to avoid that...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could create a custom decorator and use the argparse module to check for the existance of a command line switch.  Something like this:

```
import argparse
from functools import wraps

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument('-d', '--dont-run-test', dest='dont_run_test', action='store_true', default=False)
arguments = parser.parse_args()

def run(f):
    @wraps(f)
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        if not arguments.dont_run_test:
            return f(*args, **kwargs)
        else: # To demonstrate it works
            print 'Skipping test %s' % f.__name__
    return wrapper

@run
def my_test():
    print 'This should run only if the -d command line flag is not specified'

my_test()
```

Example output:

```
>python2 annotate.py
This should run only if the -d command line flag is not specified

>python2 annotate.py -d
Skipping     test my_test
```